# Does this sentence need "will"?

Tags: grammar, tense, future-time

The book I use to learn English has this example sentence,

To tell the truth, I do not want to go to the party tomorrow
because the examinations begin the day after tomorrow.

I think this should be 'because the examinations *will* begin ~'

Which is correct?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because I learnt that we use will when describing future events. In this case aren't the examinations future events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can get both tenses and be grammatically correct. But the specific use of the present tense is to indicate more than an event that **may** happen in the *near* future; it is to state that the date of that examination is already arranged and done with. There is no possibility of it being changed or altered (Kind of treated as a *fact*).

Answer (score 4):

This is what is technically known as the ***futurate***, the use of the grammatical present tense to describe events in the future. You will also see:

> I'm going to school tomorrow
>   The holidays start next week

And so on. It's completely normal, though I can see it would be baffling the first time people came across it, if their native language either doesn't do that, or doesn't have the same sort of system of tenses at all.